# Problem with Speech Recognition and Shutil in a Try Clause

Tags: python, file, audio, speech-recognition, try-except

I am trying to use speech recognition to walk through folders and name all the files based on the spoken voice content. This code currently works as long as the audio files are inside of folders which are inside of the parent folder, Audio Files (line 13). If there is an audio file inside of the 'Audio Files' folder, I get a Name Error because the 'text' variable (last line) is not defined. This makes sense, but what is odd is that this code works in the former situation.

The main problem I'm having is in the 'try' clause. When the shutil.move() function is not commented out, instead of renaming the audio files, it makes a duplicate and then renames that one, whereas when this function is outside of the 'try' clause (last line), it renames the files without being duplicated. After executing the first two lines of the 'try' clause, instead of executing the third, it executes the expect clause instead.

I'm not sure why this happens. My goal is simply to have all audio files renamed in any folder without there being duplicates.

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import sys, os, shutil, time


#folder_name = sys.argv[1]
#filename = sys.argv[1]


os.chdir(r'C:\Users\Sonorityscape\Desktop')

r = sr.Recognizer()

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('c:\\users\\sonorityscape\\desktop\\Audio Files'):
    for file in files:

        audio_file = os.path.join(root, file)

        parent_folder = os.path.basename(root)

        if os.path.isfile(audio_file):

            with sr.AudioFile(audio_file) as source:

                audio = r.listen(source)

                try:

                    text = r.recognize_google(audio)
                    #shutil.move(audio_file, root + '\\' + parent_folder + ' - ' + text.capitalize() + '.wav')
                    print(file + '  --->  {} - {}'.format(parent_folder, text.capitalize()) + '.wav')

                except:

                    print(file + '  --->  Sorry, could not recongnize anything.')


            shutil.move(audio_file, root + '\\' + parent_folder + ' - ' + text.capitalize() + '.wav')
```

Comment: So the problem is with the commented out line `#shutil.move(audio_file, root + '\\' + parent_folder + ' - ' + text.capitalize() + '.wav')` ?

Comment: Yes when I activate that line and comment out the last line, it duplicates the audio files and then renames them instead of just renaming them. It also only executes 2/3 lines of the try clause and then goes to the except clause.

Comment: Have you checked if  with `sr.AudioFile(audio_file) as source` locks the file so that there is simply no way to change the name?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure how I could confirm that, but that could possibly be the problem as when shutil.move() is outside of that line it successfully renames the file instead of duplicating it.

Comment: I have no way of testing it right now. But I guess you could simply store the files you want to change and then change them in a later step? Then again I am not really sure if this is the root of the problem.

Comment: I got it working by returning the text from a function. See answer below.

Answer (score 0):

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import sys, os, shutil, time


#folder_name = sys.argv[1]
#filename = sys.argv[1]


os.chdir(r'C:\Users\Sonorityscape\Desktop')

r = sr.Recognizer()

def audio_file_rename(audio_file):

    with sr.AudioFile(audio_file) as source:

        audio = r.listen(source)

        try:

            text = r.recognize_google(audio)
            return text

        except:

            print(file + '  --->  Sorry, could not recongnize anything.')


for root, dirs, files in os.walk('c:\\users\\sonorityscape\\desktop\\Audio Files'):
    for file in files:

        audio_file = os.path.join(root, file)

        parent_folder = os.path.basename(root)

        if os.path.isfile(audio_file):

            text = audio_file_rename(audio_file)

            if text != None:

                shutil.move(audio_file, root + '\\' + parent_folder + ' - ' + text.capitalize() + '.wav')
                print(file + '  --->  {} - {}'.format(parent_folder, text.capitalize()) + '.wav')

            else:

                continue
```